# Can I have different font style/sizes in the same graphviz record?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the following simple graph and I want to have only the text `GetArea()` in italics. Is this possible?

```
digraph {
  rankdir = BT;
  node [shape=record];
  cPolygon [label="{cPolygon|GetArea()}"];
  {rank=same; cSquare cTriangle}
  cSquare -> cPolygon;
  cTriangle -> cPolygon;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use [HTML like](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/shapes.html#html) labels:

```
digraph {
  rankdir = BT;
  node [shape=record];
  cPolygon [label=<<table border="0"><tr><td>cPolygon</td></tr><tr><td><i>GetArea()</i></td></tr></table>>];
  {rank=same; cSquare cTriangle}
  cSquare -> cPolygon;
  cTriangle -> cPolygon;
}
```

yields

[image]

*edit*

a horizontal row:

```
...
  cPolygon [label=<<table border="0"><tr><td>cPolygon</td></tr><hr/><tr><td><i>GetArea()</i></td></tr></table>>];
...
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a horizontal line in cPolygon?

Comment: Thanks, but I need the line to touch both the sides of the box; I'm drawing a UML diagram.